# Nativescript Angular IOS : File/photos Uploading Issues to server

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript, nativescript-angular, nativescript-plugin

Nativescript version - 8.4.7,
Angular 15,
IOS 17.

When uploading more than 2 photos to server/Microsoft api in the slow network (LTE 1 or 2 bars). The photos are not uploading and returning below exception. Looks like the request is not even reaching the server.

```js
error
  {
    "headers": {
      "normalizedNames": {},
      "lazyUpdate": null,
      "headers": {}
    },
    "status": 0,
    "statusText": "Unknown Error",
    "url": "https://abc",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure response for "https://abc": 0 Unknown Error",
    "error": {}
  }
```

When connected to a strong network LTE 3 or more bars ,5g or WIFI , I am able to upload more than 50 photos at once without any issues.

Here is my upload code

```js
 //component

    uploadPhotos(): void {
        let message;
        this.photos = this.service.getPhotosToUpload();
        if (this.photos !== null && this.photos.length > 0) {
            const photosList$ = new Array<Observable<boolean[]>>;

            this.photos.forEach(photo=> {
                const observable = this.submitPhoto(photo)
                if (observable) {
                    photosList$.push(observable);
                }

            });

            zip(photosList$)
                .pipe(
                    switchMap((flags: boolean[][], index: number) => {
                        let totalNotuploaded = 0;
                        let totalUploaded = 0;
                        const results =[]
                        flags.forEach((flag) => {
                            totalNotuploaded += flag.filter(falses => !falses).length;
                            totalUploaded += flag.filter(trues => trues).length;
                        });
                        results.push([totalNotuploaded, totalUploaded])
                        return of(results);
                    })
                ).subscribe((results: number[][]) => {
                    let notuploaded = results[0][0] ;
                    let uploaded = results[0][1];

                    this.message = `Uploaded ${uploaded} Photo(s).`;

                    if (notuploaded > 0) {
                        this.message += `Errors uploading ${notuploaded}`
                    
                    }
                });


        } else {
            this.message = `Uploaded 0 Photos.`;
        }
    }

    submitPhoto(photo: PhotoWrapper): Observable<boolean[]> {

        const photosToUpload$ = new Array<Observable<boolean>>();
        const photosToUpload = photo.filter((filter) => !filter.Uploaded);

        photosToUpload.forEach(photo => {

            photo.FileContent = this.servic.getFileAsBase64String(new Path(photo.File.directory as any, photo.File.relativePath));
            const observable = this.service.upload(photo);
            photosToUpload$.push(
                observable.pipe(
                    catchError(() => {
                        return of(null)
                    }),
                    tap((result: PhotoResult) => {
                        if (result?.flag) {
                            //do something
                        }
                    }),
                    switchMap((result: PhotoResult) => {
                        return of(result && result?.flag ? true : false)
                    })
                ));
        });
        if (photosToUpload$ && photosToUpload$.length) {
            return forkJoin(photosToUpload$);
        } else { return null; }

    }
    
    //upload service
    
    upload(photosData: PhotoWrapper): Observable<PhotoResult> {
        let headers = this.authService.getAuthHeader();
        let url = this.configurationService.uploadPhotoUrl();

        return this.http.post<boolean>(this.configurationService.uploadPhotoUrl(), photoDto, { headers: headers, observe: 'response' }).pipe(
            map((result) =>( {flag: result.body, wrapper: photosData} as PhotoResult)),
            
            );
    }

}
```

can anyone help me on how to fix this issue or is there any setting on the ios/nativescript/angular side which will prevent this to happen or is something wrong with my upload code?

are my requests getting timed out? , is there any way to increase the timeout or http request file size in native script/IOS or angular? not sure what the issue is and i am stuck?